# How can you perform OS Command Injection when single-quotes are filtered?

Tags: injection, bash

While attempting OS Command Injection on a `url.com/?ping=` parameter, I see that all single quotes `'` are being escaped and replaced by `\\'`.

This is problematic because whenever you submit a value to `?ping=` it's wrapped with two single quotes (e.g. `1.1.1.1` becomes `'1.1.1.1'`.

So, sending a traditional payload such as `1.1.1.1;ls` becomes `'1.1.1.1;ls'` (wrapped in single quotes, nullifying the attempt to execute `ls`.

How can I escape `'` to achieve code execution?

Comment: Relevant: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/155864/bypass-filtering-of-single-quote-for-xss-in-input-field

Comment: In this case its PHP performing the filtering

Comment: This sounds like a homework assignment, so I'm disinclined to just _give_ you the answer, but here's a hint: have you attempted to break the escaping logic? Frequently it's a very basic string-replace rule, and doesn't necessarily account for context such as nearby characters.

Comment: Have you tried [percent-encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_encoding#Percent-encoding_in_a_URI) it? `%27` might do the trick.